# using pageinit() instead of document.ready

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried many ways of using my app as a jquerymobile but didn't succeed. 
I know I have to use pageinit instead of document ready. Can you please show me the right way to do it. When I add it, it just simply not working. Here is code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    try {
        $(function() {});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").change(function() {
            $.post("test2.php",
            $("#myform").serialize());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-page" data-role="page">
        <form name="myform" id="myform" method="get">
            <label for="DogalGaz">Doğal Gaz</label>
            <select name="DogalGaz" id="DogalGaz" data-theme="" data-role="slider">
                <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

What i did was, just simply send the form data to test2.php file and process. Thank you for any help

Comment: Did you read http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html?

Comment: Yes I did. But I'm quite now on this jq and javascript. Best way to help me just edit my code. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'....

Comment: `live()` does not exist in jQuery 1.9, you can use `on()` instead. That said, I would suggest you update your question with the jQuery Mobile code you tried, so we can see how you bind to `pageinit` and the other issues you may be running into.

Comment: Thanks Hamidi, I just updated my code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

The [Flip Toggle Switch](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#entry-examples) should have 2 options instead of 3.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function() {
        $("#myform").change(function() { // use #myform instead of form to only serialize one form.
            $.post("test2.php",
              $("#myform").serialize());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-page" data-role="page">
        <!-- include action and method in case javascript handler fails -->
        <form name="myform" id="myform" action="test2.php" method="post"> 
            <label for="DogalGaz">Doğal Gaz. Seçiniz: </label>
            <select name="DogalGaz" id="DogalGaz" data-theme="" data-role="slider">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will post to test2.php every time you switch the toggle.

Comment: Do you also want to display the results of test2.php on the page?